# Line Breaks are stripped off when direction property is found

Tags: filters, plugin-wpml, wp-autop, plugin-tinymce, line-breaks

The line breaks are stripped off when the `p` tag has a `dir` attribute inserted, to explain further I'll list some examples.

Let's say we have 2 lines of text as following

```
<p>Text Paragraph Number One Goes Here</p>
<p>Text Paragraph Number Two Goes Here</p>
```

If I want to add line breaks between the two paragraphs it works fine to become like:

```
<p>Text Paragraph Number One Goes Here</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Text Paragraph Number Two Goes Here</p>
```

However if the paragraphs have a `dir` attribute as below

```
<p dir="ltr">Text Paragraph Number One Goes Here</p>
<p dir="ltr">Text Paragraph Number Two Goes Here</p>
```

All `<p dir="ltr">&nbsp;</p>` are removed and no line breaks are inserted.

The site has TinyMCE plugin which has an option to keep paragraph tags in the Classic block and the Classic Editor but this didn't solve the problem. I disabled the plugin and also didn't resolve the issue.

And also I added the `wpautop` hook in functions

```
  remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
  remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

This also didn't resolve the issue.

The line breaks works perfectly if `p` tags have no direction attribute while when it has the `dir` attribute like this `<p dir="ltr">&nbsp;</p>` they are removed.

Any line break after it gets stripped off especially if it's a non-latin language.

Comment: you should ask this in the TinyMCE Advanced support forum, it's not possible to answer this in a generic WordPress way, and 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here. Knowledge specific to the TinyMCE Advanced plugin is necessary to solve this.

Comment: But this not only related to the plugin itself

Comment: so this happens when the TinyMCE Advanced plugin is uninstalled and you manually add the `dir="ltr"` attribute via the HTML editor? Can you be more specific what you mean by stripped off?

Comment: Yes that's true when I deactivate the plugin and add it manually the same result the p tags get stripped

Comment: even in Gutenberg? Note that 3rd party plugin dev support is off-topic and your questions text is heavily focused on that plugin, if the plugin is not relevant to the question then you should edit that out as it would be a red herring. I also do not understand what you mean by stripped, I can think of multiple things that could mean. E.g. everything after the paragraph with the ltr attribute is removed. Or the paragraphs have no contents. Or the `ltr` attribute was removed. Or the paragraphs that have an `ltr` attribute are removed. Or do you mean the p tags are removed leaving just text?

Comment: The question is edited and restructured and straight to the point `<p dir="ltr">&nbsp;</p>` are removed while `<p>&nbsp;</p>` are not

Comment: Oooooh you meant empty paragaphs. The literal meaning of a line break is a newline in the HTML source which wouldn't show up anyway which doesn't make a lot of sense. It's removing paragraph tags that do not have the `dir` attribute is what you were trying to say

Comment: I've just inserted your HTML into a custom HTML block, added `dir` attributes to the paragraphs, and saw no change, and could not reproduce the issue, all blank/empty paragraphs were preserved when previewing with no stripping or removal. The behaviour you are trying to undo is not coming from WordPress itself. As an aside, is this not what a spacer block is for? And have you confirmed the theme or WPML aren't the cause by switching to a default theme? Also why are you adding `dir`? Those aren't allowed in the normal security stripping, so they should be turned back to normal `p` tags

Comment: I suspect you're unaware of the `unfiltered_html` filter, and because you're an administrator it's letting you put in arbitrary HTML and doing something that's normally not allowed, in order to fix a problem you haven't mentioned that you suspect adding `dir` tags will resolve for you

Comment: Thanks for the update, how's it possible to allow the 'dir' attribute in the tag so it doesn't get removed?

Comment: can you give some context for why you needed it in the first place and what problem it solves for you? Does WPML not provide a solution? Normally people don't put a `dir` attribute in there so a mistake has been made earlier on in the process or a misunderstanding. Even then it's unnecessary if the goal is to change the direction, CSS can do that too via HTML classes

Comment: It's required to use `dir` in the text due that multi-language might be in the same page or even all languages shown on the pages so this is required. Again once this is set we can't break lines or split paragraphs if needed with more spaces

Comment: That's not true, an `rtl` class and the `direction` CSS property `.rtl { direction: rtl; }` will also work. The solution you have chosen and attempted is not the only solution. Likewise shortcodes would solve this problem, as would a containing block. `<p class="rtl">This is RTL text</p>` works just fine. It does not answer your question, but it does solve your problem. This is a classic X Y Problem. Even WPML documentation recommends using the `direction` CSS property

Comment: note however that none of this explains why your p tags were removed, there's a very high probability that a plugin or theme has added a filter that's interfering and resulting in this. If it was `wp_kses_post` I would have expected just the `dir` attribute to have been stripped, not the tags or their content. If this is the case then nobody here can help identify it short of giving general advice to disable all plugins then re-enable things until the problem returns. `wpautop` is also highly unlikely to be related to this.